# Check if value of Cell is in another Sheet2.CellRange if yes, take the value of Sheet2.CellD position

Tags: openoffice-calc

OBS: im using OpenOffice, i cant use the "OpenOffice" tag, =|

i have this Sheet2:

[image]

and I'm planning to type the value of B4:B12 inside another Sheet

for example, i type in A1 the value 4, so it will fill the B with D4 and C with E4(from sourceSheet position)

Sheet1 that will get the value of D or E from Row where Sheet2.B is equal Sheet1.A

```
--A--B--C 
1|4-D4--E4 
2| 
3|7-D7--E7 
4|1-D1--E1
```

and i tried this:

```
LOOKUP(A1;Sheet2.B1:Sheet2.B12;Sheet2.D4:Sheet2.D12);
```

but its not getting the value, just return sometimes #NAME

Answer (score 0):

I believe your ranges are written incorrectly.

First, `Sheet2.B1:Sheet2.B12` should be `Sheet2.B1:B12`

Second, for the Lookup function, the searchtable and result table must be the same size (take a look at the online documentation for details).

Try this instead:

```
LOOKUP(A1;Sheet2.B1:B12;Sheet2.D1:D12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try in B1 and copied across to C1, then both down to suit:

```
=IF(ISERROR(LOOKUP($A1;Sheet2.$B$4:$B$12;Sheet2.D$4:D$12));"";LOOKUP($A1;Sheet2.$B$4:$B$12;Sheet2.D$4:D$12))
```